# Is it possible to calculate with an undefined variable value?

Tags: javascript

I am subtracting two variables from each other but i sometimes need to subtract an undefined value. But then the output of the subtraction is Nan.

```
var margeproject= omzetproject - kostenproject;
```

when they are both set it works fine but when one value is undefined i get NaN returned. For example:

```
3=6-3;
Nan=6-undefined;
```

Comment: what do u need when undefined ?

Comment: try : var margeproject = Number(omzetproject - kostenproject); should return the value of zero if either is undefined.

Comment: The result *has* to be NaN. How can it *not* be NaN? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: better to assure the variables have some numeric value; either preset (with 0?) or add || 0 on the (potentially undefined) assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var margeproject = (omzetproject || 0) - (kostenproject || 0);
```

This will use `0` instead of `undefined`, if either of the variables is `undefined`.

In case your variabled might contain strings, you could catch that like this:

```
var margeproject = ((omzetproject || 0) - (kostenproject || 0)) || 0;
```

Comment: Assuming that `omzetproject` and `kostenproject` are declared (as they should be) this will work.

Comment: pasted into console gives: ReferenceError: omzetproject is not defined

Comment: @MBottens: _"but i sometimes need to subtract an undefined value. But then the output of the subtraction is `NaN`."_ --> OP wouldn't have gotten to `NaN` if the variables weren't declared.

Comment: In the first solution, what happens if `omzetproject` is `'a'`? I'd remove that one from the answer.

Comment: @pmandell: Oh whoops, that's completely broken (returning `0` whenever a variable is undefined). removed.

Comment: @KooiInc: OP: _"My variables may be undefined, what should I do?"_ Solution: _"Better check if these variables are strings, booleans, objects, arrays, or maybe even functions!"_. While you raise a valid concern in that this function breaks when using strings, I don't think these variables (`projectTurnover` & `projectCosts`) will contain strings.

Comment: @Cerbrus Escpecially in programming statements like *"I don't think these variables will contain strings"* are instantly candidate for the activation of Murphy's law.

Comment: @KooiInc: Then I suggest you add a answer that handles all possible contents of these variables... I believe such thorough error checking is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus: it's pretty simple. The answer you now removed did that. See http://jsfiddle.net/r8zxa/

Comment: @KooiInc: The answer I removed also returned `undefined - 5 === 0`, where `-5` might be desired. I could add a `( ) || 0` around the whole thing.

Comment: @Cerbrus `(undefined) || 0 - -5` would be `5`. But anyway, `parseInt` may come to the rescue. http://jsfiddle.net/4Ztsk/. I'm leaving the discussion now, time to move on.

Answer (score 0):

You should test the validity of the variable. You can't use it while it's `undefined` :

```
if (typeof kostenproject === 'undefined')
   kostenproject = defaultValue;
```